# List identical files and sort the filenames in order

Tags: perl

I'm writing a program that lists the identical files given in the argument, and sort the filename alphabetically when printing out.

If the arguments are `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, `file5`, if `file2` and `file3` are identical, and if `file4` and `file5` are identical, the output should be:

```
file1
file2, file3
file4, file5
```

What I was trying to do was to loop through every args with foreach, and test if the file exist, then compare the file content, and sort filenames using cmp

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use File::Basename;
use File::Compare;

die "Usage $0: <files>\n" if @ARGV != 1;

foreach $args(@ARGV){
    if (-e $args){
       #not sure how to do 
    }
}
```

Above is what I had just wrote and I'm not sure how could I compare contents of several files and if I want to print out the name of a file, do I just do $i = basename $file then print $i?

Comment: do you just need to compare filenames that are next to each other?  or could e.g. file1 and file5 be the same and the others all different?

Comment: how large are the files?

Comment: @ysh These information were not given in the homework so I don't really know

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a more elegant solution, but this should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Compare qw( compare );

@ARGV = sort grep -e $_, @ARGV;

my %printed;
for my $i1 (0..$#ARGV-1) {
    my $file1 = $ARGV[$i1];
    next if $printed{$file1};

    my @set = $file1;

    for my $i2 ($i+1..$#ARGV) {
        my $file2 = $ARGV[$i2];

        if (compare($file1, $file2) == 0) {
            push @set, $file2;
            $printed{$file2} = 1;
        }
    }

    print "@set\n";
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: This is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This approach calculates a SHA1 digest for each file, and uses that to determine identical files, instead of having to repeatedly compare entire files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Digest::SHA;

die "Usage: $0 FILES\n" if @ARGV == 1;

my %filegroups;
for my $file (grep { -e $_ } @ARGV) {
    push @{ $filegroups{ Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile($file)->digest } }, $file;
}

local $, = ", ";
for my $group ( sort keys %filegroups ) {
    say sort @{ $filegroups{$group} };
}
```

Running on some sample files:

```
$ perl filesort.pl file[1-5]                                                                
file2, file3
file1
file4, file5
```

The files are displayed with each group of identical files ordered in an arbitrary but consistent fashion (By sorting their digests), and then by name in each group.

If you just want a flat list of sorted file names, a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) works:

```
my @files =
  map  { $_->[0] }
  sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] || $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
  map  { [ $_, Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile($_)->digest ] } @ARGV;
```

Comment: This is very inefficient. You are reading every file whether another file has the same size or not. (Also, you might want double-check to make sure two files with the same hash are actually identical.)

Comment: @ikegami Feel free to post your own answer if you don't like other people's.

Comment: This doesn't properly sort the file names. (I posted a fix, but Shawn reverted it)